# How much stack and heap (in bytes) is required by the C function in X86

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver

The implementation of a function sum in “C” is as follows:

```
int sum(int b[], int c)
{
    int s,i;

    if (c<0)
    {
            printf("ERROR\n");
    }
    s = 0;

    for(i=0; i<c; ++i)
    {
        s = s + b[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

I'd like to know, How much stack and heap in bytes is required by the function sum in X86 Linux platform? How to know this?

Is invocation of the function from within an interrupt-handler likely to be problematic or successful?

Comment: `printf` can't run from an interrupt handler; you might be in the middle of a `printf` already when the interrupt fires.  Other than that, there's obviously no heap memory because there's no dynamic allocation.  Stack usage depends on the compiler, but should be about zero beyond the return return address; everything easily fits in registers.  Compile it and look at the compiler output to see what it does, e.g. on the Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/ is worth reading

Comment: @duong_dajgja: that's somewhat useful, but they compile with optimization disabled so nothing will get optimized away.  Unlike here where a `-O0` version of this function would use stack space for the locals.

Comment: you tagged this as linux device driver. Are you running this from inside an interrupt handler? `printf` in that context is bad. `printk` and `trace_printk` might be alternatives you'd want to look at if this is running in kernel context.

Answer (score 2):

To build upon what other users have already pointed out, I will try to address both questions of the OP.

**OP's first Question:**

> I'd like to know, How much stack and heap in bytes is required by the
>   function sum in X86 Linux platform? How to know this?

We can break this first question down into 2 parts. One is about stack size and the other is about heap size.

**Stack Size:**

To find out how much stack your function is using, you can use one of the *GCC diagnostic pragmas*, i.e. the `-Wframe-larger-than=<X>` pragma. Here is an example, on how to use it. First we add the pragma to the code and save the file.

*main.cpp*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wframe-larger-than=1"

int sum(int b[], int c) {
    int s,i;
    if (c<0) {
            printf("ERROR\n");
    }
    s = 0;
    for(i=0; i<c; ++i) {
        s = s + b[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

We can now try to compile the code:

```
junglefox@ubuntu:~$ gcc -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int sum(int*, int)’:
main.cpp:20:1: error: the frame size of 32 bytes is larger than 1 bytes [-Werror=frame-larger-than=]
 }
 ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
junglefox@ubuntu:~$
```

which reports a size of *32 bytes*.

- An alternative method to measuring the stack size is to use the `stack-usage` compiler flag in *GCC*. So, we remove or comment out the `// #pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wframe-larger-than=1"` line and try to compile the file again, as shown below.

`junglefox@ubuntu:~$ gcc -c main.cpp -fstack-usage`

This will generate a file `main.su`.

```
junglefox@ubuntu:~$ cat main.su 
main.cpp:5:5:int sum(int*, int) 48  static
```

which shows that apparently, we are using *48 bytes* of stack.

---

**Heap Size**

To find out how much heap size our program is using, we will use the `valgrind` tool `Massif`. For that we first need to add a main() function to our code (without which we cannot create a binary. And a binary is what we would need to be run with valgrind). So the `main.cpp`, looks like this now,

```
#include <stdio.h>
// #pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wframe-larger-than=1"

int sum(int b[], int c) {
    int s,i;
    if (c<0) {
            printf("ERROR\n");
    }
    s = 0;
    for(i=0; i<c; ++i) {
        s = s + b[i];
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    // As Peter pointed, uncomment one of the following lines,
    // for it to be a valid test. Also, compiler optimizations,
    // when turned on, can give different results.
    // sum(NULL,0);
    // sum(NULL,-1);
    return 0;
}
```

And now we will compile, build and run the binary with the help of valgrind, as shown here:

```
junglefox@ubuntu:~$ gcc -o main main.cpp
junglefox@ubuntu:~$ valgrind ./main --tool=massif
```

This will generate a bunch of info, which looks something like below:

```
    ==8179== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8179== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8179== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8179== Command: ./main --tool=massif
==8179== 
==8179== 
==8179== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8179==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8179==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==8179== 
==8179== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8179== 
==8179== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8179== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

which reports a total heap usage of 0 Kilobytes.

Also, as @mevets has tried to explain, you can always look into the the underlying assembly code generated by the compiler. In GCC, you could do,

```
junglefox@ubuntu:~/gcc -S main.cpp
junglefox@ubuntu:~/cat main.s
```

which will show you what your function looks like in the underlying assembly output.

**NOTE/EDIT:** But just to be complete, in C or C++, without dynamic memory allocation using `malloc()` or `new`, you as a programmer are NOT using the heap. Also, unless you are declaring an array inside your function, you are not using any significant amount of the stack.

---

**OP's second Question:**

> Is invocation of the function from within an interrupt-handler likely
>   to be problematic or successful?

As many people have kindly pointed out in the comments, do NOT use `printf()` in your *Interrupt handler*.

To quote from this [link](https://notes.shichao.io/lkd/ch7/):

> What differentiates interrupt handlers from other kernel functions 
>   is that the kernel invokes them in response to interrupts and that
>   they run in a special context called interrupt context. This special 
>   context is occasionally called atomic context because code executing 
>   in this context is unable to block.
>
> Because an interrupt can occur at any time, an interrupt handler can
>   be executed at any time. It is imperative that the handler runs
>   quickly, to resume execution of the interrupted code as soon as
>   possible.

So, apart from `printf()`, one thing that could take a long time, is how big an array you are passing to that function, when used as an `Interrupt Service Routine`. It has a complexity of `O(n)`. If `c` is too big, your program would be halted for a relatively long time till the ISR finishes going through that `for()` loop.

Comment: Nice trick for stack usage.  You forgot to enable optimization, which should reduce it to near 0 for this function, depending on what the compiler does around printf.  But your heap usage test program doesn't ever call the function you want to test.  In this case, for it to possibly use any heap at all, obviously we have to pass it invalid input so it calls printf.  But you do need to call it as part of the execution of the program for it to be a valid test.

Comment: Other ways to use stack: deeply nested function calls, especially through functions with medium to large `struct` local vars.  This is why Linux's XFS filesystem code is often a culprit in kernel-stack problems.  Obviously recursion that isn't optimized away could use a huge amount of stack, so don't do that either.

Comment: @PeterCordes, ah yes, of course. Recursion. Thank you for pointing that out. That didn't cross my mind, when I was writing that. Yes, large structs with lots of variables would indeed also eat up 'significant' amounts of stack. Thanks for bringing that up also.

Comment: @PeterCordes, strange! I compiled and ran the code again with `valgrind`, after adding a line `sum(NULL, 0);` to the `main()` function. This time the heap allocation is reported as `0`. I had optimizations turned off this time also. I removed the line, compiled again and ran again with `valgrind` and I see again heap usage as `0`. Either I was seeing things earlier, or the compiler is doing some magic here, since earlier it was reporting ~84KB of heap usage. As a final test, I used this line `sum(NULL, -1);` in the `main()` function & now the heap usage is 1KB exact - because of the `printf()`

Comment: I'd expect non-zero heap usage from glibc init functions, at least peak.  Not surprising that most of it is freed before exit.  Even if you don't include `stdio.h` or link code that contains a reference to `printf`, glibc still inits some tables and buffers.

Comment: Great explanation. 
Regarding stack usage, I noticed two different results in two different methods i.e. “-Wframe-larger-than=<X> pragma” & “-fstack-usage”, what could be the reason? 
So the worst case execution time of the function sum (buffer,n) is O(n), right? How the system behaves if n is UINTMAX_MAX and this function is invoked from within an interrupt-handler, I mean here I would like to know is there any threshold time limit for an interrupt-handler to be finished? 

Last one, what other parameters of the x86 platform which have an impact on the runtime for this ‘sum() function’?

Comment: @MuniSekhar, Why the two stack methods give two different results, I don't know. It might be some *behind the scene" stuff being done by the compiler. Still `32bytes`&`48bytes` are 'pretty close'. I don't know of any time limit imposed on servicing interrupts. What will happen is this ISR will block everything else. Then you may lose incoming data being sent by other hardware. More on that [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29495/what-is-the-maximum-length-an-interrupt-service-routine). Real-time systems are another story. Regarding X86 params, better to ask separate question.

Answer (score 0):

How much stack?  After removing the printf, 0 bytes of stack are needed; the function is simple enough to work with 3 registers:

```
.globl _sum
_sum: /* (int *b, int c); */
    mov 4(%esp), %edx
    mov 8(%esp), %ecx
    cmp $0, %ecx
    jl   badcount
    leal (%edx,%ecx,4), %ecx
    xor %eax, %eax
nxt:
    cmp %ecx, %edx
    je    done
    add (%edx), %eax
    add $4, %edx
    jmp nxt
done:
    ret
badcount:
    mov $-1, %eax
    ret
```

You need to be able to rely on a compiler to not do completely stupid stuff ( no matter what standard c## thinks ).

If you are so far into a corner that you need to count stack bytes, look for a mistake earlier in your path.  Even Frank n Furter realized that solving the symptoms was different from the cause.

Answer (score 0):

C has no concept of "stack"; and when code written in C is compiled you should think of it as being mangled into an unrecognizable form.

For example, if the caller does this:

```
    myArray[2] = 99;
    result = sum( myArray, 4);
```

Then the compiler can inline a completely separate copy of the `sum()` function, and then (using optimizations like constant folding, dead code elimination and loop unrolling) convert that separate copy of the function into (the equivalent of):

```
    result = myArray[0] + myArray[1] + 99 + myArray[3];
```

..and then annotate it (or convert to "single static assignment' form) to allow more parallelism, like:

```
    temp1 = (myArray[0] + myArray[1]); temp2 = (99 + myArray[3]);
    result = temp1 + temp2;
```

..and then convert into something like:

```
    mov eax,[myArray]
    mov ebx,[myArray+4]
    lea eax,[eax+ebx]

    mov ecx,99
    mov edx,[myArray+12]
    lea ecx,[ecx+edx]

    lea eax,[eax+ecx]

    mov [result],eax
```

..and then optimize and reorder the instructions to get:

```
    mov eax,[myArray]
    mov ebx,[myArray+4]
    mov edx,[myArray+12]
    lea eax,[eax+ebx]
    lea eax,[eax+edx+99]
    mov [result],eax
```

Notice that this looks nothing like the original code - e.g. there's no `printf()`, there's no loop and there's no branches.

Of course (given that the function isn't `static`, and assuming no link time optimization or link time code generation is being done) the compiler will probably also generate an "I know nothing about the caller" version of the function and shove that into the output object file in case the linker wants it; and (if no other object files use the function) the linker might throw that version of the function away. In that case; you can look at the code the compiler generated for the "I know nothing about the caller" version, and then make worthless/incorrect assumptions based on the amount of stack used by code that is discarded and never executed.