# How to get memory usage of program executed by gcc/g++ from MinGW under windows

Tags: windows, gcc, g++, mingw

As I mentioned I dont know how to get memory usage of executed program by gcc/g++ compiler of MinGW under windows. Is there a function like time from Linux on Windows. I tried Measure Command but not showing memory. MinGw under Windows 10

For any responses Very Thankful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much stack and heap (in bytes) is required by the C function in X86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001978/how-much-stack-and-heap-in-bytes-is-required-by-the-c-function-in-x86)

Comment: And this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488554/how-to-measure-a-functions-stack-usage-in-c).

Comment: and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)!

Comment: not answered my questions

Answer (score 0):

You can do this per process using `GetProcessMemoryInfo()`, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/collecting-memory-usage-information-for-a-process

To get the process ID of the running program for example you can use `GetCurrentProcessId()`